# I am tryiing to install pylint in vsc but I am getting an error that can't open a file

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am attaching my traceback

```
$ C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe c:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.108011\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py pip install -U pylint --user

C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't open file 'c:UsersAdmin.vscodeextensionsms-python.python-2020.8.108011pythonFilespyvsc-run-isolated.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This is the error I am getting due to which I can't even run the program in 3.8.6 64 bit python interpreter. Can anyone tell what to do?

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1

Try to install the python package for VSC.
If installed probability it's broken try to reinstall it.
Sitll not worked? Try `Method 2`

## Method 2

Brows to `c:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.108011\pythonFiles`

create a file named `pyvsc-run-isolated.py`

Put the code in the file

```
import os
import os.path
import runpy
import sys


def normalize(path):
    return os.path.normcase(os.path.normpath(path))


cwd = normalize(os.getcwd())
sys.path[:] = (p for p in sys.path if p != "" and normalize(p) != cwd)
del sys.argv[0]
module = sys.argv[0]
if module == "-c":
    ns = {}
    for code in sys.argv[1:]:
        exec(code, ns, ns)
elif module.startswith("-"):
    raise NotImplementedError(sys.argv)
elif module.endswith(".py"):
    runpy.run_path(module, run_name="__main__")
else:
    runpy.run_module(module, run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)
```

It work for most of the linux distro. I hope it will work for Wondows also.

Comment: It is started to give error. Please look another way